# Add stylesheet link from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm working on a gem that houses common CSS styles. It used to have fonts embedded and added them to the asset pipeline, but I'm trying to switch to Google Fonts.

What I want to do is add a `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/…' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` tag to the `<head>` automatically, i.e. adding the gem would add this extra stylesheet. Is that possible, or would users of the gem have to manually add this?

Comment: They would need to add something in their app's layout in order to display this link in the `head`. This `something` can either be the pure HTML anchor tag `<a>` kind of like you suggested, OR it can be like a helper method returning the `link_to` ;-)

Comment: I'm thinking middleware would be a way to brute force it, but that'd probably be hacky and I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: Yes seems to be hacky and people might be reticent to use the gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create some helper function and place it in your application layout. It can't be added automatically.